# I want a query to list tags

Tags: tags

how are you?

I want to using a string query to list tags in array and using it.

I write this query but dosen't work

```
$tags= $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy , $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = post_tag");                    

foreach($tags as $tag){
echo $tag;
}
```

please help me ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

Comment: No, you don't want to use a raw SQL query. It's always better to use the functions that come with WordPress, when they're available: better performance, future compatibility etc.

Comment: okey , but when I wrote get_terms('post_tags'); it dosen't work , just work with category

Comment: The correct taxonomy name is 'post_tag'.

Comment: Also you'll want to write `echo $tag->name`.

Answer (score 3):

This query (original can be found [here](http://www.cappelli.net/20100928/wordpress-mysql-php-sitemap.html) – I use it to make a sitemap from tags) lists **ALL** TAGS sorting by their last appearance in published posts (on the top you will find more recently used tags, despite their total count/popularity):

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT
name,
slug,
tag_history.tagdate AS lastmod FROM
(SELECT
$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AS tagid,
substr($wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt,1,10) AS tagdate FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
INNER JOIN
$wpdb->term_taxonomy ON 
$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN
$wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID=$wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
WHERE taxonomy='post_tag'
AND post_status='publish'
AND description!=''
ORDER BY
post_date_gmt DESC
) AS tag_history
INNER JOIN
$wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->terms.term_id=tag_history.tagid
GROUP BY
tag_history.tagid
ORDER BY
tag_history.tagdate DESC");
```

Remember that if you don't delete..

```
AND description!=''
```

..from query you wil get ONLY tags with description.